# Cache settings ignored by .NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, caching, asmx

I've got a WebMethod that I'm calling from jQuery AJAX. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get caching working properly on the JSON data that is returned. Here's how the C# looks:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(CacheDuration=3600)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
public static List<Items> FetchItems() { //code here}
```

I've added support for HTTP GET in my Web.Config:

```xml
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

And here's what the jQuery AJAX call looks like:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/Ajax/ItemAffinity.aspx/FetchItems?ItemID=" +
        escape($("#SearchSelectedPageID").val()),
    type: "GET",
    cache: true,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        AffinityItems = data.d;
    }
});
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the HTTP Headers of the response to allow caching:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 918821
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 10 Dec 2012 19:40:57 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Finally, setting these headers via C# does not seem to have any affect on the caching behavior:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10));
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because dyanmic data isn't cached, by default.

Here's an implementation of a custom HttpHandler that will allow it: http://www.hackification.com/2009/05/01/forcing-the-browser-to-cache-dynamic-content-in-aspnet/